# Why the operator >> doesn't work with my char device?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm currently learning linux device drivers. I have begun with an example driver, which is just a memory buffer.

My code is available on my [github](https://github.com/jmlemetayer/my-awesome-driver).

I test my driver by doing this:

```
# echo "Hello World" > /dev/mad
# cat /dev/mad
Hello World
```

This is going well but when I use the redirection operator to append something (>>), the behaviour is not the one that I expected.

```
# echo foo > /dev/mad
# echo bar >> /dev/mad
# cat /dev/mad
bar
```

I expected rather to have:

```
foo
bar
```

I have implemented the `llseek` callback and take care of the `offp` in the `read` and `write` callbacks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you write your driver to support all open modes and multiple writes properly?

Comment: You're right. I forgot the support of the flag `O_APPEND` in the `open` callback. Now, all is working fine! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to handle `O_APPEND` in your write routine. The `>>` operator opens the file with the `O_APPEND` flag, which requests your driver to seek to the end before each write operation. In your case your `mad_write` routine should check the file flags, and seek to the end before writing if `O_APPEND` is set.

See the [manual definition here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). I had a look around the Linux kernel source for examples, but very few character drivers actually handle `O_APPEND`. The best example I could find was in the [generic file code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c#L2107).

Comment: That's because most character devices are stream-oriented other than storage-oriented, which means that appending is naturally the only possible operation when writing.

Comment: Indeed, after reading the manual, I have done the [fix](https://github.com/jmlemetayer/my-awesome-driver/commit/37bc4511ace03fb867aac9ec982dcd62f7e234f3) in the `write` callback.