# proper way of writing to /sys or /proc filesystem in c

Tags: c, sysfs, procfs

what is a proper way of writing to `/proc` or `/sys` filesystem in linux in `c` ?

Can I write as I would in any other file, or are there special considerations I have to be aware of?

For example, I want to emulate `echo -n mem > /sys/power/state`. Would the following code be the right way of doing it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("/sys/power/state", "w");

    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file: /sys/power/state\n");   
        exit(1);             
    }

    fprintf(f,"%s","mem");

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  Have you tried it?

Comment: `echo` doesn't know it's writing to `sys`, why should your program?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m - as far as echo is concerned, it thinks it is writing to terminal. The redirection is handled by the shell. And I don't know whether the shell has some special handlings for /sys. After all, sys and proc do behave differently in many ways.

Comment: It writes to standard output. Shell knows nothing about `/proc` or `/sys` either.

Comment: Files in /proc/ and /sys are *files* for a good reason. The reason is the ability to access them with existing tools that handle files. If they needed special handling, it would make absolute zero sense to make them available via a file-like-but-not-quite interface.

Comment: There should be no difference in reading or writing from a `/proc` or `/sys` in C. Depending on what you want to do, you could create a proc entry as well, look here for an example https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html . In your example, I see you opening the file and close it but not reading or writing to it. Did you give it a try ?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. - that cannot be true. The files in proc and sys behave differently. For instance, they show filesize 0 bytes, even when not empty.

Comment: It's also difficult to move files in /proc or /sys.

Comment: These files are dynamic. Consider them being constantly updated by the kernel behind your back. Maintaining correct size for them is just not feasible. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @stark A filesystem doesn't have to support operations like moving or deleting.

Comment: Another limitation is that something like `echo foo >> /sys/bar` probably won't work as you expect, unless the author of the special file has [taken extra precautions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877986/append-to-a-file-in-the-proc-file-system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach lacks some error handling in the write operation.

The `fprintf` (or `fwrite`, or whatever you prefer to use) may fail, e.g. if the kernel driver behind the sysfs file doesn't like what you're writing. E.g.:

```
echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

In order to catch those errors, you MUST check the output of the `fprintf` to see if all characters that you expected to write were written, and you should also check the output of `ferror()`. E.g. if you're writing "mem", `fprintf` should return 3 and there should not be any error set in the stream.

But one additional thing is missing: sysfs are not standard files. For the previous write error to be returned correctly you MUST disable buffering in your stream, or otherwise the `fprintf` (or `fwrite)`) may happily end without any error. You can do that with `setvbuf` like this just after the `fopen`.

```
setvbuf (f, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```